# Extracting cookies from Postman Interceptor

Tags: cookies, postman

I have an application which uses websso for authentication and I want to test my APIs using Postman. I used Postman Chrome App and Postman Interceptor to capture requests. These requests work fine in Chrome App. Then I've opened my saved requests in Postman Standalone App however they are not working because cookies are not transferred. Is there a way to use those requests in standalone app together with their saved cookies?

Answer (score 1):

@canan,
Postman supports capturing requests and cookies from the v7.14. Install [Postman interceptor extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) and postman version above v7.14 and start capturing requests and cookies.

For more information on how to use interceptor go through this [learning center](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/)